# Can I make my OData request in JSON format?

Tags: ajax, json, request, query-string, odata

I know `OData` supports [*responding* in JSON format](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/json-format/) when it's given the appropriate `Accept` header:

`Accept: application/json`

Some articles say you'll need to specify odata verbosity otherwise you'll get the default xml format, but I have not seen this to be actually true. But let me mention it anyway:

`Accept: application/json;odata=verbose`

But (how) can I make my *request* using JSON instead of a querystring?

Answer (score 0):

OData doesn't provide a way to specify the query in a request body, it only supports the query in the URL. So the answer is that there's no way to do that in JSON. Note that it applies to GET requests. Modification requests (POST/PUT/...) do accept JSON as the payload (typically representing an entity for example), in which case simply specify the content type of the request in its Content-Type header.

There are java script libraries which let you build the query string using more structured code (as compared to just strings). For example the datajs http://datajs.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I don't mind POSTing. Can you edit your answer to include an example on how to format a JSON request?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I posted in my original question. Unless I am overlooking things, this has no information about requests, only about responses.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that. Take a look at this: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/json-verbose-format/#41_Representing_an_Entity. The JSON Verbose format is effectively identical in V3 and V2 (there are only very minor changes). This document also describes the differences between requests and responses.